# How to solve equations of the form $z^n= f(c, i)$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to solve equations of the form $z^n= f(c, i)$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

That is, the L.H.S. is a complex number to $n$th power and the R.H.S. is some expression involving constant(s) $c$ and $i$.

Taking the $n$th root seems to be problematic.
 Is e.g. $\sqrt{1+i}$ even defined?

Comment: if you have lhs , rhs you can just square and then perform algebra

Answer (score 0):

Any expression involving some constants and $i$ can be written as $re^{i\theta}$. This way, the problem becomes $z^n=re^{i\theta}$, which we can solve by simply taking the $n$-th root. The solutions will then be $$\{\sqrt[n]{r}e^{i\left(\tfrac{\theta+2k\pi}n\right)}| k\in\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\} \}$$
Also, yes, $\sqrt{i+1}$ is definitely defined, and it is, in polar coordinates, equal to $\sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}8}$.

Hope this helped!